# Send auto response once issue is tracked in SharePoint - From column

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, office-365, issue-tracking

So i have created a issue tracker form/list for our team within SharePoint.

Is it possible to create a flow where it sends and email to the person added (via outlook directory) in a column?

E.g -

We receive a IT request
Team member adds into issue tracker 
 
Flow triggers email to the person who has requested assistance - (Column populated from outlook directory)

Is this possible?

any advise please

Answer (score 1):

The person field is synced with Active directory, so it can be used anywhere in the domain either in Outlook or SharePoint.

For, this scenario you want send email to the person who creates item in the issue tracking list, then you can use the "created by" column in flow to send the email or you can create one more custom column something like "Requested By" with the person or group type - then you may refer to this column in the Microsoft Flow while sending the email.

Answer (score 0):

Habibur's reply is correct. Mostly you only need a trigger named `when an item is modified`, check the column where you need to fill in the team member is empty, if not empty, use the action `send an email notification` to send the email to people who created this request(based on the assumption the IT request is created by the user who has requested assistance).

Sample:
[image]